# How does vim "syntax cluster" highlighting work?

Tags: python, vim, syntax-highlighting, pymol

I am trying to use a vim syntax file for highlighting a PyMOL script file and got into trouble with the "syntax cluster" definitions, the vim files are from https://github.com/speleo3/PyMol-syntax . The definitions that give trouble are:

```
syntax keyword pymolOperatorK  and or not
syntax match pymolOperator1 "[!|&,()?]"
syntax cluster pymolOperator contains=pymolOperator1,pymolOperatorK
...
hi def link pymolOperator Operator
```

When editing a PyMOL file (syntax file properly loaded and other parts properly highlighted), the keywords "and, or, not" are not properly highlighted.
However, if I add the following two lines, then the highlighting is working:

```
hi def link pymolOperator1 Operator
hi def link pymolOperatorK Operator
```

Basically, it looks like the "syntax cluster" part is not working.

There is another "syntax cluster" line defined, the "pymolString" group, which has the same issue, only after I add "hi def link" individually does the corresponding highlighting work.

I also tried to move the "syntax cluster" definition before the "syntax keyword" line, still did not work.

Any comments?

Comment: You might get a better answer at vim.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks, did not know it exists.

Comment: So [I was told that "Cluster" is a logical unit](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28868/how-does-vim-syntax-cluster-highlighting-work-or-why-does-this-syntax-cluste). The text elements are still bound to ordinary syntax items.